# How to filter users list on user_status field with get_users()

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, users

I simply want to get the list of users with get_users() but filtering on the field user_status=0 so the spam and unactivated users are removed from the list.

This does not work:

```
get_users( 'user_status=0&orderby=ID&order=desc&number=' . $limit );
```

This doesn't work either:

```
$new_users = get_users( [
    'orderby'     => 'ID',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'user_status' => [ 0 ],
    'number'      => $limit
] );
```

Neither does this:

```
    $new_users = get_users( [
    'meta_key'     => 'user_status',
    'meta_value'   => '0',
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'orderby'    => 'ID',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'number'     => $limit
] );
```

So... what would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user_status` field has long been no longer used in core, so maybe that's why there is no argument that will filter the users by their `user_status` value?

However, you can use the [`pre_user_query` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_query/) to alter the user query's SQL command, i.e. to add something like a `AND user_status = 0` into the WHERE clause.

So for example, you can add this into your theme's `functions.php` file, and then just set the `user_status` argument, e.g. `get_users( 'user_status=0' )` (like you did in your first example):

```php
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'my_pre_user_query' );
function my_pre_user_query( $query ) {
    if ( isset( $query->query_vars['user_status'] ) ) {
        $query->query_where .= " AND user_status = " . (int) $query->query_vars['user_status'];
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just make a custom instance of `WP_User_Query`, then set the WHERE condition the same way it's set above (i.e. via direct modification on the `$query_where` property), like so:

```php
$query = new WP_User_Query;

$query->prepare_query( [
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    // don't set user_status
    'number'  => $limit,
] );

// Now modify the WHERE clause.
$query->query_where .= " AND user_status = 0";

// Then run the SQL command.
$query->query();

$users = $query->get_results();
var_dump( $users );
```

Comment: Splendid. I love both solutions. In my case I like the first one best because it makes all get_users() lists capable of dealing with a user_status argument instantly.